# drop the bulk table from database

Tags: sql

I want to drop bulk table from database whose name is starts with some string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create table #Temp
(
    TableName  varchar(50)
)

Insert into #Temp 
SELECT NAME FROM SYS.OBJECTS WHERE TYPE='U' NAME LIKE '%'

DECLARE @Name varchar(50)

DECLARE cursorName CURSOR -- Declare cursor

LOCAL SCROLL STATIC

FOR

Select TableName   FROM Temp

OPEN cursorName -- open the cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM cursorName

INTO @Name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN

FETCH NEXT FROM cursorName

INTO @Name

drop table @Name

END

CLOSE cursorName -- close the cursor

DEALLOCATE cursorName -- Deallocate the cursor

Note : This will work if the table which u are talking abt doesnt have table depedencies .